# Is the function below convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose $\theta_i$ for $i=1,\dots, n$ are my parameters and $w_i$ for $i=1,\dots, n$ are known constants ,  $w_i, \theta_i \in(0,1)$, and $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i=1$

$$f(\mathbf{\theta})=\frac{(\sum^n_{i=1}w_i \theta_i)^2}{n\sum_{i=1}^n(w_i\theta_i)^2}$$

If it is not convex, can it be minimised?

Comment: are $w_i$ known or variable? real valued or positive?

Comment: $w_i$ are known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is convex, but its minimum value is $1/n$, achieved when all the $\theta_i=0$ except for one of them.  Your function is the reciprocal of a convex function of the vector $v=(w_1\theta_1,\dots,w_n\theta_n)/\sum_{i=1}^n w_i\theta_i,$ which is a point on the probability simplex.  That is, your $1/f(\theta)=n\sum v_i^2$, where $\sum v_i^2$ is well known to be convex.  Convex functions defined on convex domains (such as the simplex) attain their maxima at extreme points, a.k.a. vertices of the simplex, which have all $v_i=0$ except for one of them, which is 1.

Comment: How were you able to find it's minimum? How do you know it is minimum? What about it's maximum?

Comment: I recognized your function as the reciprocal of (essentially) $\sum v_i^2$ which, as I stated in my comment, is convex and hence maximized at an extreme point.  To minimize your thing is to maximize my thing.  My thing is minimized at the centroid of the simplex, so yours is maximized when your rescaled $w \theta$ thing is at the centroid, too.

Comment: I understand you. To recap: The explanation given above is very clear,  $v_i=\frac{1}{n} \forall i$  minimises $\sum_{i=1}v_i^2$ because it exists on the "probability" simplex.  In order to maximise $f(\theta)$, we just take the values of $\theta$ for which $\sum_{i=1}v_i^2$  is minimised. With reference to my question, $w_i \forall i $ does not have to be confined in the range (0,1) - the solution is the same for another known $w_i$.

Comment: Exactly.  For a while I was scared because I had not taken your $\theta_i\in[0,1]$ constraint into account, but your overall rescaling by $\sum_i w_i\theta_i$ saves the day.